# Тревогни, чтобы начать

Tags: обсуждение, локализация

#### Несколько тезисов о переводах.

1. **Лучшее - враг хорошего.**
   Считаю, что не стоит искать гораздо наиболее лучший вариант для одной строки, если можно теми же усилиями сделать 10 просто хороших строк.
2. **Лучше сразу, чем когда-то потом.**
   Если сейчас в базе строка с ошибкой или неконсистентные строки - то их нужно заменить первым же нормальным вариантом. А потом можно спокойно подождать, когда предложат и выберут что-то ещё лучше.
3. **Контекст обязателен!**
   Варианты перевода нужно предлагать в контексте. Без него сложно оценить качество, точность и благозвучность.

Comment: Насчёт контекста вообще точно. Приходит строка из двух или одного слова и давай теперь пойми - откуда это.

Comment: В Transifex'е откуда можно угадать контекст? Я там вижу только строки без контекста. (Я сам не перевожу, так как я вряд ли могу предложить качественные переводы, но процесс все таки меня интересует)

Comment: Не сочтите за граммарнацизм, но, поскольку, топик касается переводов, считаю, что обязан поправить. "Гораздо наиболее лучший вариант" - в данном контексте слово "наиболее" употреблено некорректно. Выглядит, как ирония по поводу п. 1.

Comment: @Mik: Да, это и есть ирония по поводу поиска лучшего из лучших вариантов, вы правильно поняли. Править не нужно.

Comment: Тогда прошу меня извинить =) Глядя на такие фразы изо дня в день, становлюсь невосприимчив к сарказму на тему грамматики.

Comment: @Mik: тут ещё и заголовок неспроста содержит ошибку.

Answer (score -2):

1. Раз начали, то надо закончить.
   Кстати, там полно подобных строк.
2. Если не ошибаюсь, консистентный вариант уже сделали.
   Ну, кроме того, что у вопросов "или", а у ответов "и".
3. Все заинтересованные про контекст в курсе.
   А кто не в курсе - надо всего лишь пару ссылок щёлкнуть и посмотреть.